# How to redirect user to action method of specific controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i was reading a article on mvc for uncontrolled action `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874284/ASP-NET-MVC-Performance-Tips?msg=5003414#xx5003414xx`

they write this code for uncontrolled action

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
       RedirectToAction("Index").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
}
```

author is saying that if a user request `http://localhost:58234/default/index1, index1 action which does not exist so it will redirect to the default/index`

i want to develop a base controller and put a routine which detect action method or controller exist or not for request url. if not exist then it will redirect user to a action method of a specific controller with query string value. as a result we can show a friendly message to user.

still i got no chance to work with mvc in office. just out of curiosity i like to know how to achieve the functionality with `base controller`?

help me with sample code. thanks

Comment: Check this for what you wanted to achieve http://iamlevi.net/asp-net-mvc-4-auto-correcting-unknown-actions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to Do like So.
Just do like this .
Manage `Application_Error` event form `Global.asax` file .

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //process 404 HTTP errors
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
                Response.Clear();
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

                // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
                IController errorController = "Your Controller";

                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

                errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));

        }
    }
```

Hope this help .

Comment: this line is giving error `EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWebHelper>` not compiling. do i need to include any assembly?

Comment: does your solution handle when user give incorrect controller or action name ?

Comment: IWebHelper used as application global interface to get common thing as error controller .

Comment: can u plzz give full code as a result i could understand the usage of IWebHelper.

Comment: I am working on multi tired application .`EngineContext.Corrent` return a [Singletone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance .`Resolve` using for [D I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) .`IWebHelper` class contain property like `ErrorController` etc ...

Comment: now your code pretty clear to me thanks but u forgot to answer one question that is `does your solution handle when user give incorrect controller or action name ?`

Comment: Really it execute new controller that we created .`"Your Controller"` means new controller that we create in controller folder in mvc .

Comment: i asked when user request a url like http://localhost:58234/default/index1 and no action called index1 does not exist then Application_Error will be invoked ? or suppose there no controller exist called default then Application_Error will be invoked ? please answer this question thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can simply create base class as follows

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
        {
            //Your code
            RedirectToAction("Index").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }
    }
```

And your all controller should inherit `BaseController` instead of `Controller`.

**UseCase**

```
YOURDOMAIN.COM\CorrectController\InCorrectActionMethod // `HandleUnknownAction` will be called

YOURDOMAIN.COM\InCorrectController\InCorrectActionMethod // `HandleUnknownAction` will be not be called, in this case 404 will be thrown.
```

Comment: How does HandleUnknownAction get invoked?

Comment: So whenever if invalid action method is found then this `HandleUnknownAction` , will be invoked, in-case if controller name it self is not correct then this it will not be invoked.

Comment: Who tells MVC handler to invoke this method and not HandleUnknownAction123()?

Comment: Method name it self describe its duty, Check this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

this method will Called when a request matches this controller, but no method with the specified action name is found in the controller.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know about this method in Controller class. +1

Comment: basically i want to show a friendly message when controller name is incorrect given or action method name is incorrect given. guide me how to handle this situation. thanks

Comment: Simply, you can put your message in `viewbag` or `tempdata`, and redirect it to your `error.cshtml` page, and in your view, you can print your message from `viewbag` or `tempdata`, but yeah in-case if controller name itself is incorrect, then it'll be 404 and it can't be tracked here, you need to have a different approach for that.